# Sort and arrange values in dataframe in a specific order

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have the following data in dataframe

```
Folder Name   ID     File Name        
Test          2      2_Accounts.csv      
Test          4      4_Contacts.csv         
Test          2      2_Contacts.csv
Test          4      4_Accounts.csv
Test          4      4_Leads.csv
Test          2      2_Leads.csv
Test          2      2_Opps.csv
Test          4      4_Opps.csv
```

I first need to sort by ID so ID's with same value are grouped together.
I did the following

```
df = df.sort_values("ID")
Folder Name   ID     File Name        
Test          2      2_Leads.csv    
Test          2      2_Accounts.csv         
Test          2      2_Contacts.csv
Test          2      2_Opps.csv
Test          4      4_Accounts.csv
Test          4      4_Opps.csv
Test          4      4_Leads.csv
Test          4      4_Contacts.csv
```

Next I need to sort within groups(id) in a way that "Contacts" should come first, "Accounts" should come second, and the rest can follow in any order

The should output should look something like this

```
Folder Name   ID     File Name        
Test          2      2_Contacts.csv      
Test          2      2_Accounts.csv         
Test          2      2_Opps.csv
Test          2      2_Leads.csv
Test          4      4_Contacts.csv
Test          4      4_Accounts.csv
Test          4      4_Leads.csv
Test          4      4_Opps.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a temporary column to set custom order: 0 -> Contact, 1 -> Accounts, * -> the rest

```
df['order'] = df['File Name'].replace({r'Contact': 0,
                                       r'Accounts': 1,
                                       r'.*': 2}, regex=True)

out = df.sort_values(['ID', 'order']).drop(columns='order')
```

```
>>> out
  Folder Name  ID       File Name
2        Test   2  2_Contacts.csv
0        Test   2  2_Accounts.csv
5        Test   2     2_Leads.csv
6        Test   2      2_Opps.csv
1        Test   4  4_Contacts.csv
3        Test   4  4_Accounts.csv
4        Test   4     4_Leads.csv
7        Test   4      4_Opps.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort on more than one column at a time to get what part way to you want.

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['ID', 'File Name'])
```

2_A comes before 2_C so you could create a new column that alters the File Name text to come up with the order you want, for example, create a temp column that strips out the 2_ and then delete the column if you don't need it.

```
df['sort file name col'] = df['File Name'].str.replace('\\A[0-9]_', '')
df = df.sort_values(by=['ID', 'sort file name col'])
del df['sort file name col']
```

Comment: How does that put all contacts on top?

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: And what if theres a `5_Cat.csv` in the column?

Comment: Then you'd need different regex or do something else.

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning a pseudo column that forces "Contacts" to be ranked above others.
Like so:

```
>>> df.assign(file_type=~df["File Name"].str.contains("Contacts")*1) \
      .sort_values(["ID", "file_type"]) \
      .drop("file_type",axis=1) \
      .reset_index(drop=True)

  Folder Name  ID       File Name
0        Test   2  2_Contacts.csv
1        Test   2  2_Accounts.csv
2        Test   2     2_Leads.csv
3        Test   2      2_Opps.csv
4        Test   4  4_Contacts.csv
5        Test   4  4_Accounts.csv
6        Test   4     4_Leads.csv
7        Test   4      4_Opps.csv
```

1. Create a column called "file_type" that assigns a value of 0 if the file has the word "Contacts" in it and 0 otherwise.
2. Sort the dataframe by columns "ID" and "file_type"
3. Drop the created column
4. Reset index